# Can't instantiate UI5 classes due to "TypeError: ... is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sapui5

I'm trying to refactor the legacy UI5-codebase and would like to use reusable dialogs.

My steps:

1. I've downloaded the [Walkthrough Step 19: Reuse Dialogs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/19453962b8074b7399372c65cbe05370) sample
2. I've added `HelloDialog.js` into project's `./controller/` folder
3. I've added `HelloDialog.fragment.xml` into project's `./view/` folder
4. I've adjusted a namespace inside of `HelloDialog.js` and `HelloDialog.fragment.xml` from `sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.controller.HelloDialog` to `webapp.controller.HelloDialog`
5. I've added a button for the `HelloDialog` to the view:

```xml
<Button id = "helloDialogButton"
        icon = "sap-icon://world"
        text = "Show Popup"
        press = ".onOpenDialog" />
```

6. I've added to `App.controller.js`:

```js
onOpenDialog() {
    this.getOwnerComponent().openHelloDialog();
},
```

7. I've added `"./controller/HelloDialog"` to `Component.js` and initialize the object:

```js
init(...args) {
    UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, args);
    this.getRouter().initialize();
    this._helloDialog = new HelloDialog(this.getRootControl());
}
```

8. I've added hooks to the `exit` and `openHelloDialog` events to `Component.js`:

```js
exit() {
    this._helloDialog.destroy();
    delete this._helloDialog;
},

openHelloDialog() {
    this._helloDialog.open();
},
```

Now, I run the project and get the a blank page, in DevTools console I see the following error:

> Failed to load component for container `rootComponentContainer`. Reason: TypeError: `HelloDialog` is not a constructor

[image: screenshot showing the TypeError: "HelloDialog is not a constructor"]

The only difference I can spot is that **I'm using arrow functions in my code**, but can it be that arrow functions break UI5? Perhaps, some issues with the object context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors of UI5 classes should avoid arrow functions:

```js
// constructor: () => {/*...*/}
constructor: function() { // e.g. in HelloDialog.js
  // Avoid arrow functions in UI5 class constructors
},
```

The same applies to constructors in VanillaJS. Calling `new` on arrow functions is [**not** supported!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#cannot_be_used_as_constructors)

---

Also note that arrow functions do not create their own context (`this`) either. Their context is based on the *scope* where the arrow function is defined which is often times the `window` object. Hence, methods should not be defined with arrow expression if `this` in the function body is supposed to refer to its class instance.

For further restrictions, see the linked documentation above.